# OpenCV GUI issue in Python

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I am trying trying to display webcam footage using openCV on Ubuntu but i am getting the following error:

> Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9Major opcode:
>   62 (X_CopyArea)Resource id:  0x3800056]

Here is my full code

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap.set(3,320)
cap.set(4,240)
while(1):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have tried googling the error and it seems to be GUI related.
I have also read the docs on imshow and I seem to be calling it fine, can anyone figure out why I am getting this error.

Thanks

Comment: Is frame non null and does it actually contain an image?

Comment: i can run this on raspbian and it works fine. and the camera light turns on so I am assuming it is not null, how would I check?

Comment: Try debugging it.  Do you have 2 cameras? If I remember correctly the default camera is on number 0, therefor you might need `cv2.VideoCapture(0)`.

Comment: I have tried 2 different cameras at different points in the hardware array. 0, 1 and the webcam works though other applications (i.e Cheese)

Comment: What if you try the example from the documentations? https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

Comment: i get the same error with the example script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a [problem](https://github.com/P0cL4bs/WiFi-Pumpkin/issues/53) when Python tries to present the window. It's probably an OS issue. Try editing the `/etc/environment`.

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Add this line:

```
QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
```

Also try running your app as `sudo` and checking [this](https://li8bot.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/opencvpython-part-1-working-with-videos/) for any solutions if before mentioned doesn't help.

Comment: Thank you!! this fixed the issue.

Comment: Glad to help :) Please accept the answer if it solved your issue.